# How is it possible to remember Krishna at the time of death?

Tags: krishna

Since it is quite well known that those who remember Krishna at the last moment preceeding death get Moksha.( Gita 8:5 and Gita 8:6)

But people are generally unconscious at the time of death , then how is it possible to remember Krishna at the time of death ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is our next destination (next birth or heaven/hell) determined by our last moment of death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50355/is-our-next-destination-next-birth-or-heaven-hell-determined-by-our-last-momen)

Comment: You are right. This is extremely hard to do in practise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate. Just because the other question does not have an upvoted answer does not mean another one should pop up especially when that question is not even 2 weeks old

Comment: daily early morning recite gajendra moksha stotrA from srimad bhagavatam. Kirshna gave  assurance to people who chant whole heartedly Gajendra moksha stotra will remember sri krishna at the time of death.. like fasting on ekadashi is also mandatory for this because sins prevent one from remembering the lord